# listener in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

How to use event listener in symfony.
Is that possible like in java?
i.e. when I select a value from a choice list , I can get the selected value. Could listener be applicabled?

```
$builder          
            ->add('numberrange', 'entity', array(
              'class'    => 'TelnOperatorBundle:Numberrange',
              'property' => 'De',
              'multiple' => true,

            ));

            $id= $builder->getData()->getNumberrange();
            $builder->add('subnumbers', 'entity', array(
              'class'    => 'TelnOperatorBundle:Subnumber',
              'property' => 'Fromsub',
              'multiple' => true,
              'query_builder' => function(\Teln\OperatorBundle\Entity\SubnumberRepository $er) use ($id)
                                         {

                                         $qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('t')
                                                  ->where('t.numberrange =:id')
                                                  ->setParameter('id', $id); 

                                          return $qb;

                                          },
              ));
```

Comment: What is it with all those questions about the `\Teln\OperatorBundle`. Is there a new tutorial out there using this bundle name as an example or are you creating a new account every time you ask a question?

Answer (score 0):

Despite your question is vague and you seem to skip googling, you may want to stick to jQuery / Javascript listeners: [Read this](http://api.jquery.com/on/). It explains how to set listeners the jQuery way.

Comment: I am asking about the possibility in symfony. I am still a biginner

Comment: PHP (as Symfony works on PHP) is a server side language. A server side, preprocessed language (PHP, ASP, JSP) can't receive click events directly, as, once the browser gets the PHP page, stops talking to the server. You should go for client side events (jQuery, Javascript) and make Ajax calls to Symfony if you need server information

Answer (score 0):

First of all: What have you tried?

Second: No, it's not possible. What do you want to achieve can only be done with JavaScript (much more easier when using jQuery).

You can send the result from the clicking event via AJAX to a Symfony controller and evaluate the values, do some magic and return whatever you want and then process the returned data on your website.

Comment: what I want is as follows : I have a form with two fields. I 'll join the code. When I select a value in the first field(what I to translate with a event listener) I want to get it and depending on it, I will display the appropriate values in the next field @akluth

Comment: AJAX is perfect for this. Listen with jQuery on the element, when the user selects a value send the value via AJAX to a controller which does the desired action, send back the result and parse it in your client-side JavaScript code.

Comment: could you plz provide me with a basic tutorial on how to implement ajax, jquery and js in symfony. I am really a beginner at that @akluth

Comment: There's no comprehensive tutorial which covers all of the topics above in one tutorial and that's not even needed. What do you want to accomplish does not depend on Symfony (you can call a server side script in what-ever-language via AJAX, you can even call simple HTML files).

Have a look at http://learn.jquery.com/ where you can learn the jQuery basics. A simple, yet effective tutorial for Ajax and jQuery (in german, but you should get the idea): http://www.benny-design.eu/tutorials/ajax-tutorial/